# Game code structure using openGL / Android

Tags: android, opengl-es2, data-structure, assets, architecture

My game will have 3 activities (splashscreen, options menu and main game).

As it stands, each is a separate activity with it's own activity class and GLSurfaceview class.

Is this structure the right way of doing things?

Secondly, I wish to load all my bitmaps in my Splashscreen activity 'up front' but if I do this, how exactly do I access / reference them from other classes / activities?

Appreciate if someone could clear this up for me.

Comment: Is it working for you? Are you having any problems with it?

Comment: Not sure what's ''not clear' about this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this structure the right way of doing things?

Nothing wrong with that setup. I'd just be careful about the Splash screen. Splash screens (for Android) are meant as a temporarily placeholder to show that something is loading. If your App takes less then a second to load, then you shouldn't have a splash screen.  Too many people make splash screens when they truly aren't needed.  Here's some interesting info about [Android splash screens](http://blog.iangclifton.com/2011/01/01/android-splash-screens-done-right/).

You can load all your bitmaps by extending the Application class. In a way, it can provide global variables that persist between Activities. Generally, not a good practice for Android Apps, however games can be a good exception. Here's a link. [Extending Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/708317/1243753).